# Валидность кода блока Поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте!

Валидатор https://validator.w3.org находит атрибуты datа невалидными - http://joxi.ru/KAx7YNbikVzk28 (скриншот).

Это можно как-то обойти, чтобы угодить валидатору?

Кнопки отличные и удалять их не хотелось бы ни за что.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Извини, но никак. В социальных сетях, которые не используют фреймы для отображения контента со страницы (например facebook с их `data-href, data-layout, data-action` как атрибутами для div'а вместо `iframe`), никак не выйдет угодить валидатору. Но плюнь на это, если сайт работает хорошо и без твоих ошибок допущенных в коде, то все в порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Валидатор ругается не на дата-атрибуты, а на несоответствующий им [doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype).

Например, следующая разметка является полностью валидным HTML5-документом.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Yay</title>
<div data-x="foo"></div>
```